# Can you submit to appStore for Xamarin.ios without a mac

Tags: xamarin.ios

We were having a discussion in my uni class and couldn't find the answer we were looking for. Do you need to compile a project written in C# with Xamarin on a mac to submit it to the appStore?

Answer (score 1):

You need a Mac to *BUILD* a Xamarin.IOS app.  The application loader tools used to submit a binary to the App store are also available only on Mac.